# How to parse case-insensitive strings with JSR-310 DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, jsr310

JSR-310 has a handy class `DateTimeFormatter` which allows you to construct a `DateTimeFormatter`. I particularly like the `pattern(String)` method - see [javadoc](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/time/calendar/format/DateTimeFormatters.html#pattern%28java.lang.String%29)

However, I hit a problem whereby this is case sensitive -- e.g.

```
DateTimeFormatters.pattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

matches with "01-Jan-2012", but not with "01-JAN-2012" or "01-jan-2012".

One approach would be to break the string down and parse components, or another would be to use Regex to replace the case-insensitive strings with the case-sensitive string.

But it feels like there ought to be an easier way...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

And there is... according to the [User Guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=User_Guide#Formatting) (offline, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--) instead), you should use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to build a complex `DateTimeFormatter`

e.g.

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.parseCaseInsensitive();
builder.appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = builder.toFormatter();
```

Comment: Slightly neater third line: builder.appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");

Comment: Slightly neater: most of the times, a builder provides methods *returning* the builder, so you can use *method chaining*: `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern...`.

Comment: Further improvement: [Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573). Use `.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)` in this case.

Answer (score 11):

This alternative is usefull for initializating static variables:

```
DateTimeFormatter myFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                               .parseCaseInsensitive()
                               .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                               .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Seems to duplicate the [accepted Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10797809/642706) from a couple years earlier

Answer (score 5):

Just an extra Note, the order matters.

This is case insensitive:

```
            DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .parseLenient()
                .appendPattern("HH:mm EEEE")
                .toFormatter();
```

This is not:

```
            DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("HH:mm EEEE")
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .parseLenient()
                .toFormatter();
```

Comment: Good point! Further improvement: [Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573). Use `.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)` in this case.