# Parsing date in scala (java time api)

Tags: java, scala, datetime, java-8

Hi I'm trying to parse a string with a date in scala. I tried it the following way:

```
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
   import java.time.LocalDateTime
    val date="20 October 2015"
    val formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy")
    val dt=LocalDateTime.parse(ts,formatter)
```

But I get the follwing exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20 october 2015' could not be parsed at index 3
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
  at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
  ... 29 elided
```

For parsing I used the Standard Java API's [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Comment: what is ts here?? val dt=LocalDateTime.parse(ts,formatter)

Comment: Please include enough code for us to reproduce the issue, or at least gain a little more context.

Comment: You haven't shown your `ts` string but it appears to have a lower case `october` which the parser does not like - `October` works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10797808/2670892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusion about [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) with [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), `LocalDateTime` is used with `Year`, `Month`, `Day` with `Times`, like:

```
println(LocalDateTime.now())
> 2017-03-13T15:11:42.559
```

and `LocalDate` is used with `Year`, `Month`and `Day` without **Time**, like:

```
println(LocalDate.now())
> 2017-03-13
```

As your example, you should use: `LocalDate` to parse **time** text, like:

```
LocalDate.parse(date,formatter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
val dt=LocalDate.parse(date,formatter)
```

instead of LocalDateTime since your date string doesn't contain any time information.

Comment: Does not solve the Issue: scala> val dt=LocalDate.parse(ts,formatter)
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24 December 2016' could not be parsed at index 3
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
  at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)

Comment: That's strange, '24 December 2016' works for me. Do you have a non english system language? Could you try to construct your formatter with a locale:  val formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US)