# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 3

Tags: java-8, java-time, date-parsing

I am using Java 8 to parse the the date and find difference between two dates.

Here is my snippet:

```
String date1 ="01-JAN-2017";
String date2 = "02-FEB-2017";

DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter .ofPattern("DD-MMM-YYYY", en);
LocalDate  d1 = LocalDate.parse(date1, df);
LocalDate  d2 = LocalDate.parse(date2, df);

Long datediff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1,d2);
```

When I run I get the error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: Try to use "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse case-insensitive strings with jsr310 DateTimeFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797808/how-to-parse-case-insensitive-strings-with-jsr310-datetimeformatter)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following code works. The problem is you are using "JAN" instead of "Jan".
DateTimeFormatter does not recognize that it seems. and also change the pattern to 
"d-MMM-yyyy".

```
  String date1 ="01-Jan-2017";
  String date2 = "02-Feb-2017";

  DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
  LocalDate  d1 = LocalDate.parse(date1, df);
  LocalDate  d2 = LocalDate.parse(date2, df);

  Long datediff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1,d2);
```

Source: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate/

Comment: Thanks. It works. I have a another question. Will it take care of DayLightSaving time also ?

Comment: You won’t have any problems with daylight saving time, @Uma. Even if DST begins, say, on March 26, there is still exactly 1 day from March 25 to March 26. When using `LocalDate` it is completely ignored that there really are only 23 hours. In fact, `LocalDate` ignores any time zone and therefore any DST completely.

Answer (score 68):

First of all, [check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). The uppercase `D` represents the **day-of-year** field (not the **day-of-month** as you want), and uppercase `Y` represents the **week-based-year** field (not the **year** as you want). The correct patterns are the lowercase letters `d` and `y`.

Also, you're using month names in uppercase letters (`JAN` and `FEB`), so your formatter must be **case insensitive** (the default behaviour is to accept only values like `Jan` and `Feb`). And these  month names are English abbreviations, so you must also use English locale to make sure it parses the names correctly (using `java.util.Locale` class).

So, your formatter should be created like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // case insensitive to parse JAN and FEB
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // add pattern
    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    // create formatter (use English Locale to parse month names)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This will make your code work (and `datediff` will be `32`).

Comment: Really great answer. Covers everything relevant and is right to the point.

Comment: Adding the Locale was critical and not obvious from my error message (DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 0).  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thank you! It was essential to add the Locale.ENGLISH is order to override the system default based on the region.

Answer (score 3):

```
// DateTimeFormatterBuilder provides custom way to create a
    // formatter
    // It is Case Insensitive, Nov , nov and NOV will be treated same
    DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")).toFormatter();
    try {
        LocalDate datetime = LocalDate.parse("2019-DeC-22", f);
        System.out.println(datetime); // 2019-12-22
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // Exception handling message/mechanism/logging as per company standard
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this wildcard,

```
 String d2arr[] = {
            "2016-12-21",
            "1/17/2016",
            "1/3/2016",
            "11/23/2016",
            "OCT 20 2016",
            "Oct 22 2016",
            "Oct 23", // default year is 2016
            "OCT 24",  // default year is 2016
    };

    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive().parseLenient()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2016L)
            .appendPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd]")
            .appendPattern("[M/dd/yyyy]")
            .appendPattern("[M/d/yyyy]")
            .appendPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy]")
            .appendPattern("[MMM dd yyyy]");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = builder.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

https://coderanch.com/t/677142/java/DateTimeParseException-Text-parsed-unparsed-text[enter link description here](https://coderanch.com/t/677142/java/DateTimeParseException-Text-parsed-unparsed-text)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Someone is looking for this it will work with date Format like **3/24/2022** or **11/24/2022**

> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy")

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy");
       formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US );  // Locale specifies human language for translating, and cultural norms for lowercase/uppercase and abbreviations and such. Example: Locale.US or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("3/24/2022", formatter);
        System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: I did try this and it hasn't worked for me. It only worked by using the parseCaseInsensitive() that was mentioned in other solutions.