# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException for dd-MMM-yy format

Tags: java

I am trying for hours now to parse this String to LocalDate and I just can't find where my pattern is wrong.

```
 public void parseDate() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd'-'MMM'-'yy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("05-Sep-20", formatter);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05-Sep-20' could not be parsed at index 3
```

It works fine when using the pattern `dd'-'MMMM'-'yy` or `dd'-'MM'-'yy`, but it just won't work for `MMM`

I used the single quotes around the dash, because otherwise I was getting a parsing exception at a different index.

I am using Java1.8 and `java.time`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925840/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-could-not-be-parsed-at-index-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be your locale. Try this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd'-'MMM'-'yy", Locale.US);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("05-Sep-20", formatter);
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928297