# TimeZoneConversion - CST to UTC

Tags: java-8

I have a date value in Central Time

**String cstDate =  "02-JAN-19 03.34.33.540260000 AM";**

I have to convert above string value to UTC format. I am using Java 1.8 and used ZonedDateTime.

Please find below code.

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a";      
String cstDate =  "02-JAN-19 03.34.33.540260000 AM";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(cstDate,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));        //CST+6
System.out.println("cst : " + cstDate);
System.out.println("utc : " + utcDateTime);
```

But getting an exception :  Text '02-JAN-19 03.34.33.540260000 AM' could not be parsed at index 3

Not understanding why I am getting this exception.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse case-insensitive strings with jsr310 DateTimeFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797808/how-to-parse-case-insensitive-strings-with-jsr310-datetimeformatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Your `JAN` value is not properly localized to English, so we must parse using a more customized `DateTimeFormatter` object produced via the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class to parse without case-sensitivity.

## UTC

UTC is not a “format”. [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the baseline against which we measure time zones around the globe. All time zones are some number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC. Time zones east of the demarcation point at the [Royal Observatory, Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory%2C_Greenwich) are ahead of UTC, and those to the west are behind. An offset of zero is UTC itself.

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. This is bad practice, as the value is ambiguous. Without zone or offset, we must parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

We specify a formatting pattern to match your input. By the way, your choice of an input string format is less than optimal. Whenever possible, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

Your input value of `JAN` is incorrect localization for the US and UK and likely others. So we cannot depend on the usual parsing. We must indicate parsing with case-insensitivity. To do so, we must [build up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object by using the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class.

```
String input = "02-JAN-19 03.34.33.540260000 AM" ;

DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern(
        "dd-MMM-uu hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a"
    ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = builder.toFormatter( Locale.US ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2019-01-02T03:34:33.540260

Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC means our `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It represents *potential* moments along a range of 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe). To determine a moment, we must assign an offset or zone.

## `ZonedDateTime`

You claim to know that this input string was meant to represent a moment in `CST`. Unfortunately, `CST` is not a real time zone. Never use these 2-4 character pseudo-zones, as they are not standardized — they are not even unique! Did you mean *China Standard Time*? Maybe *Central Standard Time* in the Americas?

[Real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) have a name in `Continent/Region` format. I will guess that you meant a time zone such as `America/Chicago`. You have comment mentioning an offset of `+6`… did you mean `-06:00` as used by `America/Chicago` in the winter?

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
```

Apply this time zone to our `LocalDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime` representing an actual moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-01-02T03:34:33.540260-06:00[America/Chicago]

To see that same moment as UTC, extract an `Instant`. An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-01-02T09:34:33.540260Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/L9vYRG).

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your Question was not clear. If you meant the input string is known to represent a moment in UTC, parse as a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Adjust into `America/Chicago` time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It resolved my issue to a certain extent.CST I meant Central Standard Time. Now I am getting output in below format.                  
Input String[CST] : "02-JAN-19 03.34.33.540260000 AM"                                          Output String[UTC] ":2019-01-02T09:34:33.540260Z"                                                   But I need output in below format : "2019-01-02 09:34:33"

Comment: @SuryaJoseph Search for the `DateTimeFormatter` class and its `ofPattern` method. This has been covered many many many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am not able to use DateTimeFormatter and ofPattern due to incompatible types.