# Java 11 can't convert String To LocalDateTime in some case

Tags: java, java-11

I have these code below:

```
private void convertStringDatePosted() {
    String stringDatePosted = "20 Janeiro 2021 00:26";
    Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "MZ");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm").withLocale(locale);
    LocalDateTime aa = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDatePosted, formatter);
    System.out.println(aa);
}
```

When I ran code with java 8, it work. But with java 11, it throw this Exception: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20 Janeiro 2021 00:26' could not be parsed at index 3.

I also have a similar situation with the case where there is a zone in the string I want to convert, the code is:

```
protected LocalDateTime getDatePosted() {
    String dateScraped = "2021-08-15 09:00:28 (UTC+01:00)";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (z)");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateScraped, formatter);
}
```

If run with java 8, it still work but with java 11 it not. The Exception is:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20 Janeiro 2021 00:26' could not be parsed at index 24.

This error occur on macOS, i have not try on other OS yet.

I don't know if this error is due to java version or something else. Looking forward to your reply. Thanks a lot!

Comment: From a quick google, you'll find that in Portuguese, the names of the months are spelled in lowercase. See [this](https://ielanguages.com/portuguese-months.html) for example. So the expected way to write the date is "20 janeiro 2021 00:26"

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797808/how-to-parse-case-insensitive-strings-with-jsr310-datetimeformatter

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, my code worked. But I don't know the difference between java 11 and java 8, why does it work in one version and not the other?

Comment: The reason why it worked in Java 8 was probably a bug. By [searching for "portuguese" in the bugs database](https://www.oracle.com/search/results/_/N-8d?No=0&Nr=106&Nrpp=10&Ntk=S3&Ntt=portuguese&cat=bugs), there are quite a lot of similar bugs related to not outputting the month name in the correct case. This specific bug is not reported though. I would imagine it got fixed as the result of fixing another bug, or someone just fixed it directly without reporting it.

Comment: Oh, that's useful information. Really thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: Default locale data (including month names in different languages) are different in Java 8 and 11. See for example [JDK dateformatter parsing DayOfWeek in German locale, java8 vs java9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244724/jdk-dateformatter-parsing-dayofweek-in-german-locale-java8-vs-java9)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your the second of your examples. Your `getDatePosted()` runs fine on my Oracle jdk-11.0.3 on Mac and returns `2021-08-15T09:00:28`.

Comment: oh, this is so weird. I will try to find out the cause on my laptop. Thanks for the information you provided

Answer (score 1):

### Capital or small J in janeiro?

It seems to me that there are two bugs: One in your string, which should have a small j in *janeiro*, and one in Java 8, which accepts the capital J that you had. Said having learned just a few words of Portuguese when I was in Portugal some decades ago

Month names in different languages are a part of the *locale data*. Java can get its locale data from up to four sources. The default in Java 8 is Java’s built-in locale data from since early versions of Java. From Java 9 the default is CLDR, Unicode Common Locale Data Repository. So in Java 8 Java’s own locale data have the upper case J. CLDR, which is also available in Java 8 through a system property, has a small j. An interesting observation is that when I instruct Java 11 to use Java’s own locale data, it also shows the small j. The error from Java 8 has been fixed.

There are many possible solutions. One is to instruct your formatter not to care about case when parsing:

```
    String stringDatePosted = "20 Janeiro 2021 00:26";
    Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "MZ");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
            .toFormatter(locale);
    LocalDateTime aa = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDatePosted, formatter);
    System.out.println(aa);
```

Output is:

> 2021-01-20T00:26

### Parsing the UTC offset

I have not been able to reproduce your other example. Your `getDatePosted` method runs fine on my Oracle jdk-11.0.3 on Mac and returns `2021-08-15T09:00:28`. I don’t know why it did not on your computer.

There’s another problem with your code, though: You are parsing into a `LocalDateTime` thus throwing the time zone information away. Don’t do that. For example the strings `2021-08-15 09:00:28 (UTC-12:00)` and `2021-08-15 09:00:28 (UTC+14:00)` denote very different points in tome, 26 hours apart, but will be parsed into the same `LocalDateTime`. Parse into a `ZonedDateTime` to retain the time zone. If you need the time in a different time zone (such as your own), convert to a `ZonedDateTime` in that time zone. Do not use `LocalDateTime` if by any means you can avoid it.

**Workaround:** If you cannot get parsing of `UTC+01:00` as a time zone to work, the following hack does it:

```
protected OffsetDateTime getDatePosted() {
    String dateScraped = "2021-08-15 09:00:28 (UTC+01:00)";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ('UTC'xxx)", Locale.ROOT);
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateScraped, formatter);
}
```

Now the method returns `2021-08-15T09:00:28+01:00`. You also notice that the UTC offset has been retained.

### Link

Related question with more information on locale data in different Java versions: [JDK dateformatter parsing DayOfWeek in German locale, java8 vs java9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244724/jdk-dateformatter-parsing-dayofweek-in-german-locale-java8-vs-java9)

Comment: Thank you very much. These are very interesting knowledge. I wish you a good day. <3